# CMake compilation error..(Unknown CMake command "QT4_WRAP_UI")

Tags: cmake, qgis

im trying to build grass plugin for qgis ..

when i try to use cmake ..    i get the following error after configuring..

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:78 (QT4_WRAP_UI):
   Unknown CMake command "QT4_WRAP_UI".
```

I have Qt4 ,PyQt and python2.6 installed already..

can anyone help me how to figure out whats wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to import the Qt4 macros from CMake. A line like this should do it:

```
find_package(Qt4)
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to just locating the package you should include ${QT_USE_FILE}, that is:

```
find_package(Qt4)
include(${QT_USE_FILE})
```