# CMake compilation error: Unknown CMake command "PYQT4_WRAP_UI"

Tags: python, compilation, centos, centos6, qgis

I am tring to compile QGIS1.8 on CentOS6.3 after reading this this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637079/cmake-compilation-error-unknown-cmake-command-qt4-wrap-ui).

I have added the below code into `/qgis-1.8.0/python/CMakeLists.txt` at the top 1,2,3 line

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
find_package(Qt4)
include(${QT_USE_FILE})
```

However I still have the below errors:

```
CMake Error at plugins/plugin_installer/CMakeLists.txt:18 (PYQT4_WRAP_UI):
Unknown CMake command "PYQT4_WRAP_UI".
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
-- Cache values
CMAKE_BACKWARDS_COMPATIBILITY:STRING=2.4
CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=
CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/usr/local
EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH:PATH=
LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH:PATH=
QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/qmake-qt4
```

How can I continue to compile the qgis source code?

Comment: Hi cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6) have you added this line on top of the text file as specified at the bottom

Comment: I have added the code but it still product the error